# normal subgroup generated by a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G= \langle g_1,g_2 \rangle$, and let $H\leq G$ given by $H=\langle g_1 g_2 g_{1}^{-1}g_{2}^{-1}\rangle$. 
What is the normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $H$?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be possible to say anything in particular about this? I think it might be possible for it to be pretty much anything.

Comment: @Tobias, the normal closure of H is G' so it is fairly restricted.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Is that obvious? I can see that it will be contained in $G'$, but it is not quite obvious to me that it will be all of it (I might just be missing something).

Comment: I think answering the question in case of the free group would give enough insight for the general case...

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, i don't know if it is just the commutator subgroup or not!

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know if something isn't clear. Certainly $H$ need not be the derived subgroup, but its normal closure is.

Comment: but why $H$ need not be a subgroup?

Comment: @Danial: H is a subgroup, but it need not be the derived subgroup. For instance if G is alternating group of degree 4 and order 12, then it is generated by two elements, their commutator has order 2, so H is order 2 and G' is order 4.

Comment: @Danial: $H$ is a subgroup, by definition. It might not be normal, for instance if $G$ is free, it doesn't have $g_2^{-1}g_1g_2g_1^{-1}$.

Comment: ok.. thank u so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $N$ be the normal closure of $H$. Since $[g_1,g_2] \in N$, $[g_1N,g_2N]=1N$ and $G/N$ is generated by two commuting elements, so is commutative as a whole. Hence $G' \leq N$. However, $G'$ is a normal subgroup containing the commutator $[g_1,g_2]$, so $H \leq G'$ and so $N \leq G'$. Hence $N=G'$.

Comment: yes that what i was looking for.. the answer then is the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Ahh, that was quite obvious after all.

Comment: but how did you deduce that $G'\leq N$?

Comment: Let $x,y \in G$. Since $G/N$ is abelian, $[xN,yN]=1N$ so $[x,y] \in N$ so $G' \leq N$.